# Regular Expression to replace "\r\n" only if not preceded by "." in a string

Tags: regex, c#-4.0

Could you please provide a regular expression that I can use to replace all `\r\n` in a string, only when `\r\n` is *not* preceded by `.`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To match a character, you can place the character inside brackets such as `[.]`. To *not* match it, you can start the character list with a caret such as `[^.]`. This will effectively match any character that is not a `.`.

For your specific case, you want to match `\r\n` that doesn't have a `.` in front of it. Combined with the above, you can use:

```
[^.]\r\n
```

To replace it, you'll want to "capture" the character that is not-a-period to keep it in the replacement. You can capture it by wrapping it in parentheses, such as `([^.])`.

Using [`Regex.Replace()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7f5w83z.aspx), it would be something like:

```
yourString = Regex.Replace(yourString, @"([^.])\r\n", "$1");
```

The `$1` is the character matched and is re-replaced back into the string, now stripped of the `\r\n`.

Comment: Good answer, even though I don't think the OP deserves it because he/she showed absolutely no effort in solving the problem.

Comment: @RuiJarimba My effort in trying to solve this problem wound me up here. It's not like no one in the world will ever have this problem again.

Answer (score 2):

I think this would work

```
Regex.Replace(input, @"([^.]?)\r\n", "$1");
```